# Dynamic added fields values are not posting in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i have a dynamic form which i want to insert the data to mysql but the newly added field values are undefined in php it only post the value of fields that are already in html.
And after i click on place order in alert it will only display the first input value which is already in html.

In console it does not have any errors and each row has its own name and id
This is my form:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 ">
<div class="card"> <div class="card-body float-right "> <form id="purchase_order_form" name="purchase_order_form"><button type="button" name="po_place_order" id="place_order" class="btn btn-primary">Place Order</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center">
                    <h4>Purchase Order Details:</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body  text-center align-content-center">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table id="dynamic_field" class="table table-hover ">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product Name</th>                     <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Unit Cost ( <?php echo $purchse_order->currency_symbol(); ?> )</th>
                                <th>Total ( <?php echo $purchse_order->currency_symbol(); ?> )</th>
                                <th>Add/Del</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="selector " id="productnames" name="pod_product_name[]">
                                                <option>Choose Products</option>
                                                <?php $purchse_order_func->fetchProducts(); ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="number" id='qty' placeholder="Quantity" name="pod_quantity[]"
                                                   class="form-control">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="number" id="unitPrice"
                                                   name="pod_unit_cost[]"  class="form-control" placeholder="unit Price">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="number" id="total"
                                                   placeholder="Total Price <?php echo $purchse_order->currency_symbol(); ?>"
                                                   readonly class="form-control total">
                                        </td>;
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" id="add" name="add" value="+" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
                                            <button type="button" id="remove" name="remove" value="-" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
</form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){

        var i=1;
        $('#add').click(function (){
            i++;

            html = "<tr id='row"+i+"'>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<select class='selector' id='PN"+i+"' name='pod_product_name[]'>" +
                "<option>Choose Prods</option>"+
                "<?php $purchse_order_func->fetchProducts(); ?>" +
                "</select>" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<input type='number' id='QTY"+i+"' placeholder='Quantity' name='pod_quantity[]'" + "class='form-control quantity '>" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<input type='number' id='UP"+i+"'" +
                "placeholder='Unit Price <?php echo $purchse_order->currency_symbol(); ?>' " +
                "name='pod_unit_cost[]' class='form-control unit_price'>" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<input type='number'  id='total"+i+"'" +
                "placeholder='Total Price <?php echo $purchse_order->currency_symbol(); ?>' " +
                "readonly class='form-control total'>" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<button type='button' id='addx' name='addx' value='+' class='btn btn-xs btn-info'><i " +
                "class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i></button>" +
                "<button type='button' id='"+i+"' name='remove' value='-' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_remove'>" +
                "<i class='fa fa-minus'></i></button>" +
                "</td> " +
                "</tr>";

            $('#dynamic_field').append(html);

});
$('#place_order').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                url :"includes/Operate.php",
                data: $("#purchase_order_form").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })

        });
```

And at last the php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['pod_product_name'])){
            $ar  =  $_POST['pod_product_name'];
            $ar2 =  $_POST['pod_quantity'];
            $ar3 =  $_POST['pod_unit_cost'];
            echo print_r($_POST);
}
```

I dont receive any error only the dynamic input data is not posted in array!

Really I've been reading every other post and no hope it has been week now that im stuck! And appreciate any help! Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need `echo` before `print_r`

Comment: If you examine the form in the DOM inspector, are the dynamic fields inside the `<form>`?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you need to concatenate `i` to `id="addx"`, like all the other IDs in the dynamic row.

Comment: @barmar thanks for replying!  Yes all the newly added fields are visible and editable in cosole! Sorry about echo

Comment: Once elements are added to the DOM, there's no difference between static and dynamic elements. So if they're nested correctly, `serialize()` will include them.

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend checking the DOM again to make sure everything is nested properly.

Comment: I have removed the form out of the card and it worked! Thanks Sir! Your nesting idea helped!!